# codeigniter Active Record : Fields lost when performing a JOIN

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, join

When I perform a join with CI's Active Record, sometimes the result won't show all the fields. For example when a join is performed with tables that has same field names, one of the table's field won't show up in the results.

Example :

```
=== TABLE users ===
id INT(10)
first_name VARCHAR(255)
last_name VARCHAR(255)

=== TABLE messages ===
id INT(10)
exp_id INT(10)
dest_id INT(10)
content TEXT

=== CONTENT OF THE DATABASE ===
INSERT INTO users VALUES (1, "Bob", "Smith");
INSERT INTO users VALUES (2, "Graig", "Anderson");
INSERT INTO messages VALUES (999, 1, 2, "Hello Graig!");

=== the query ===
$this->db->where('messages.id', 999);
$this->db->join('users exp', 'users.id=messages.exp_id', 'INNER');
$this->db->join('users dest', 'users.id=messages.dest_id', 'INNER');
$res = $this->db->get('messages');

== the result ===
id      exp_id  dest_id content         first_name  last_name
999     1       2       Hello Graig!    Bob         Smith
```

I can't retreive both "dest.first_name" and "dest.first_name". The table "dest" is in the join() but there is a conflict with the table "exp", which also has the fields "first_name" and "last_name". Actually this is not a CI problem this is how MySQL behaves.

It can be fixed using select / aliases, but is there a way to optionnaly make CI append (or prepend) the alias of a joined table to its fields? So the result could look like this :

```
id      exp_id  dest_id content         id_exp  first_name_exp  last_name_exp   id_dest first_name_dest last_name_dest
999     1       2       Hello Graig!    1       Bob             Smith           2       Graig           Anderson
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"when a join is performed with tables that has same field names, one of the table's field won't show up in the results."

is exactly your issue, and this is standard sql for any db & not codeigniter. The last instance of a field name will always be the one selected, even if you use "SELECT * ...".

The short answer is, No, there's no functionality like that in CI. Using your aliases as you suggested is the solution; to make it yourslef would involve extending the core db driver classes, which I'm guessing is far more work than you'd be interested in

Using an ORM would probably solve this issue, but I don't think this by itself is reason enough to do that

Answer (score 1):

I have same your error. And I find the solution for this issue:

```
        === the query ===
    $this->db->select('messages.*');
    $this->db->select('exp.id as exp_id, exp.firstname as exp_firstname, exp.lastname as exp_lastname');
    $this->db->select('dest.id as dest_id, dest.firstname as dest_firstname, dest.lastname as dest_lastname');
    $this->db->where('messages.id', 999);
    $this->db->join('users as exp', 'users.id=messages.exp_id', 'INNER');
    $this->db->join('users as dest', 'users.id=messages.dest_id', 'INNER');
    $res = $this->db->get('messages');
```

So the result could look like this:

```
id    exp_id  dest_id    content      exp_id  exp_firstname exp_lastname   dest_id    dest_firstname     dest_lastname
999     1       2       Hello Graig!    1       Bob             Smith         2          Graig              Anderson
```